# Why is query_start null for a lot of queries (postgresql)?

Tags: postgresql

I'm running the following query:

```
`SELECT query_start, query, pid, state FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE datname='${my_database}' AND usename='${my_user}' AND pid<>pg_backend_pid() ORDER BY query_start;`
```

Whilst there are many rows with meaningful info like:

[image]

there are also many rows with null info:

[image]

Is this normal?  These null entries don't seem to persist, so maybe they just relate to queries that are in the process of being set up?  Or something?

Comment: Look at all the rest of the columns to see if that gives a clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is the `state` column: those which have no `query_start` are the ones with `state = 'idle'`. Idle connections are not currently executing a query.

What is confusing you is that the `query` column is **not**, as you assume, the currently running query, but *the last query that was executed on that connection*.

Comment: So what does it mean when `query_start` is `null`... a connection that is open but which hasn't yet run any query (but soon will)?  So it's quite normal, and not an indication that I'm somehow creating orphaned connections (by not closing them) or anything like that?

Comment: It is a connection where a statement has run in the past, but is completed now. That is perfectly normal.

Comment: OK, thanks!  Good to know, from someone who knows!